# add/remove class on website ready

Tags: jquery

I have a ul list(which serves as menu) in which dependig on which website I am, I want to remove and to and class to specific items.

this is the list

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="/index.php">Homepage</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/projects.php">Blog/Projects</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/aboutme.php"<>About Me</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/quotes.php"<>Quotes</a></l
</ul>
```

And this is the jQuery code that I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $pathname = $(location).attr('pathname');
    $('ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-justified li a').each(function( i ) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('active');
    if ($this.attr('href') == $pathname) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
    });
});
```

If I want to change css code whit this "template" I can do that, but if I run this code it does nothing.

How can I rewritre this code so that I it works.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I am a bit confused, do you want the active class to be added to the `a` element or the parent `li` element?

Comment: @kidA I want them to be added to the a element

Comment: You sure? So you want to have anchor element and its parent with same class? Doesn't make much of a sense. If you are targeting the `li` element you can do `$(i.target).closest('li').removeClass('active')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you targeting the anchor instead of just the list item, when that's whats classed? Oh well. This seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // $varname usually means a jQuery object
    // This is just a string.
    var pathname = location.pathname
    // Why not just give this ul an ID
    $('ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-justified li a').each(function (i) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().removeClass('active');
        if ($this.attr('href') == pathname) {
            $this.parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e85vv3fe/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathname = location.pathname;
    $('ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-justified li a').each(function( i ) {
        var link = $(this);
        link.removeClass('active');
        if (link.attr('href') == pathname) {
            link.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't redefine `this`, use another identifier. Using `$` in an identifier (as the OP has done) is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I am sorry to say that it still dosent work. I have also tried with another identifiers, but nothing

Comment: location is the part of jQuery. It is given in the code.

Comment: Sorry to say but still nothing, I have tried whit changing of the css style and it works, but not for removing or adding classes

Comment: Ah, you need the pathname, not the href. `var pathname = location.pathname;`